# "Download Network Failed" - Chrome failes on 160kb tiff file in React Redux app

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, http

So I have been looking around.  Obviously there's a fair amt of on the web about these "Download Network Failded" problems.  I feel our problem is somewhat unique in that we have one file.  a 160kb tiff file (really it's a blog that we append a tiff extension too). I just stumbled on this when testing.  It's a random image on my machine.  I have much bigger and smaller files that process fine through the app.  When debugging, the response looks good in fiddler, like any other good response. Also tracking the response through our React app it looks good all the way through.  So the problem happens somewhere in Chrome and just for this one file.  We've tried all standard stuff found here.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/7XBU6g6_Ktc

Mainly fiddling with extensions (disabling them), download locations, reinstalling, etc.  But the idea that is one smaller jpg file we are sending for conversion (the app is a basic convertor) has me perplexed.  Has anyone ever seen something like this??

So here is how we handle the file in our redux action.

WE use these packages

```
import dataURLtoBlob from 'dataurl-to-blob';
import FileSaver from 'file-saver';
```

And we have a  dispatch function we pass in for a response in our thunk (the fetch)

```
export function saveFile(data, fileName) {
return (dispatch) => {
    var ie = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s([\d.]+)/),
        ie11 = navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7.0/) && navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/),
        ieEDGE = navigator.userAgent.match(/Edge/g),
        ieVer = (ie ? ie[1] : (ie11 ? 11 : (ieEDGE ? 12 : -1)));

    if (ie && ieVer < 10) {
        console.log("No blobs on IE ver<10");
        return;
    }

    var mimeType = data.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
    var extension = '';
    if (mimeType.includes("zip")) {
        extension = "zip"
    }
    else {
        extension = mimeType.substr(mimeType.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    }

    var npmBlob = dataURLtoBlob(data);

    if (ieVer > -1) {
        FileSaver.saveAs(npmBlob, fileName + "." + extension);
    } else {
        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        downloadLink.href = data;
        downloadLink.download = fileName;
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
}
```

Relevant part of the fetch itself

```
             }).then(response => {
            //debugger;
            var responseObj = JSON.parse(response);

            //handle multi-retrieve
            if (targetExtension.includes("/File/Retrieve")) {
                for (let array of responseObj) {
                    if (array.ReturnDocument) {
                        if (responseObj.length > 1) {
                            dispatch(saveFile(responseObj[0].ReturnDocument, "testFiles_download"));
                        } else {
                            dispatch(saveFile(responseObj[0].ReturnDocument, responseObj[0].ticketID));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            var returnObject = { returnResult: responseObj, loading: false };
            return callback(returnObject);
```

Everything looks good.  http status codes are 200 and all other files are working.  There is really nothing special about this jpg we send in as far as we can tell.  And it looks good coming back.

Here is the request sent in:

```
POST http://redacted/api/File/Convert HTTP/1.1
Host: redacted-dev
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 168078
Origin: http://redacted-dev
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryhgZddb45UOHBhsgs
Accept: */*
Referer: http://redacted-dev/ui/Convert
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Here is the raw response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 02 Jan 2018 14:12:17 GMT
Content-Length: 3707173
```

Here is what the blob looks like when we get it back(abbreviated):

```
 ReturnDocument=data:image/tiff;base64,SUkqAAg+............
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [file saver package](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/#filesaverjs) to download a blob object.

Usage Example is as below:

//  FileSaver Usage

```
          import FileSaver from 'file-saver';
          fetch('/records/download', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
          }).then(function(response) {
            return response.blob();
          }).then(function(blob) {
            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'fileName.zip');
          })
```

One more way to download a file is that you make a get request which sends file from the server.
Then you can simply do the following:
window.open('full server link');

Then your file will get start downloading.

Comment: so we are using a package called 'dataurl-to-blob' to do what you referring to here I think.  I updated my post to reflect how we handle that.  So I think we have that covered no? Please look at the original post again. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: the first if is for IE, else use chrome or firefox or whatever.

Comment: if (ieVer > -1) {
        FileSaver.saveAs(npmBlob, fileName + "." + extension);
    } else {
        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        downloadLink.href = data;
        downloadLink.download = fileName;
        downloadLink.click();
    }

Comment: After converting the data to a blob then the FileSaver will save the file. So you can pass your blob object into  it and your file will get download

Comment: apologies, we use the dataurl-to-blob to send.  FileSaver is reference. file-saver package.  We are using that package.

Comment: AWESOME MAN!!  Long story short.  A while back we had started with that downloadLink approach which honestly worked fine in Chrome.  Then we ran into problems with IE, so we used the other way for that thinking it was an IE hack we needed to work around.  But I guess it caught up to us.  No more downloadLink.  Just file-saver approach for all browsers now.  You were 100% on target, we just need to clean up our code. This is better.  Still think it's weird it didn't work on that one file. And only after we redux'd the app.  But all is well now.  Accepted.  Upvoted.  Thanks!!